# Remove button in react app missing first click on page load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a little React app that displays a list of disease Ids.

I have this mysterious issue that I've been trying to fix but have so far been unsuccessful.

I have this set of table columns,  that you see below.

It's a small table that just contains a column of IDs and a column with two buttons:  Remove | Keep

What the buttons do are this:

When you click on Keep, nothing happens, the disease stays in the table.

But if you click Remove, the disease is removed from the list right away without any page reload.

Clicking remove will fire a function called handleRemove.  This function first calls updateDisease, which sets the 'isRemoved' value of the disease object.
 Then it calls fetchAndUpdate to get the new list with that disease removed.

The problem I am encountering is this.

When I first load the page, the first time I click 'Remove', nothing happens on the page.

However I do see the console.log messages in the 'handleRemove' function with the correct disease object.

But the second time I click remove, everything works fine for the remainder of the session.

I've tested this over and over, moved things around, but I always run into this issue.

I was hoping another pair of eyes could take a look and see if they find anything that could be causing this behavior.

```
const updateDisease = async (disease, newIsRemovedVal) => {
    disease.isRemoved = newIsRemovedVal;
    await axios({
        method: "PUT",
        url: "api/diseases/" + disease.id,
        data: JSON.stringify(disease),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    });
};

const handleRemove = (e) => {
    console.log("Remove!");
    updateDisease(e, 1);
    fetchAndUpdate();
}

const handleKeep = (e) => {
    conaole.log("Keep!");
    updateDisease(e, 0);
}

const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => handleRemove [

        {
            Header: 'Disease List',
            columns: [
                {
                    Header: 'ID',
                    accessor: 'id',
                },
                {
                    Header: 'Remove/Keep',
                    Cell: ({ row }) =>
                        <div><Button onClick={() => handleRemove(row.original)}>Remove</Button>&nbsp
                            <Button onClick={() => handleKeep(row.original)}>Keep</Button></div>
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [handleRemove, handleKeep]
)

const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

const fetchAndUpdate = useCallback(() => {
    diseaseData(false).then(res => {
        setData(res.data);
    });
}, [])

React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchAndUpdate()
}, [fetchAndUpdate]);
```

Please let me know if you have any thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: You could return a promise in updateDisease and then do `updateDisease(e, 1).then(()=>fetchAndUpdate())`

Comment: @HMR thanks but what would that promise do?  I'm sorry.  I don't see what the promise would do and how it might help. Do you mean to call fetchAndUpdate inside the updateDisease?  Thanks! :)

Comment: Does fetchAndUpdate calls an API  which gets diseasesData from server?

Comment: Hi @ShubhamKhatri yes, fetchAndUpdate is an external component that gets data from a server via api. It is just a simple const result = await axios("api/diseases/")

Comment: @HMR is a promise just an async with await?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are executing an async request in `updateDisease(e, 1);` you need to wait till the request is complete before fetching the data again from server

When you call updateDisease and fetchAndUpdate like below, even though updateDisease has await inside of it, it doesn't stop fetchAndUpdate from being called. So you data is fetched before you update it on server and hence the inconsistency.

```
const handleRemove = (e) => {
    console.log("Remove!");
    updateDisease(e, 1);
    fetchAndUpdate();
}
```

You can change the above to use async-await too like

```
const handleRemove = async (e) => {
    console.log("Remove!");
    await updateDisease(e, 1); // wait till data is updated
    fetchAndUpdate();
}
```

You can also use `.then` syntax like

```
const updateDisease = (disease, newIsRemovedVal) => {
    disease.isRemoved = newIsRemovedVal;
    return axios({
        method: "PUT",
        url: "api/diseases/" + disease.id,
        data: JSON.stringify(disease),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    });
};

const handleRemove = (e) => {
    console.log("Remove!");
    updateDisease(e, 1).then(() => {fetchAndUpdate();});

}
```

Comment: Hi when I did that, I noticed that if I click remove too fast, the page stops reacting...

Comment: Interesting, you can using .then syntax by returning promise from updateDisease and see that makes any difference

Comment: thanks do you mean like like 'await updateDisease(e, 1) then fetchAndUpdate();' ?

Comment: Thnks! When using the .then syntax, do I need to remove the async and await?